# How to get the local time zone name in Rust?

Tags: datetime, rust, timezone

I know can get the time zone offset via

```
chrono::Local::now().offset()
```

But I need a name, e.g. "America/Denver" or at least an abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding, determining the timezone name is not possible with chrono{-tz}. There seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono-tz/issues/13) titled *Detecting system timezone*, but it lacks all details.

**Update:** New crate found, which actually gives the more precise desired result.

The best crate I have found is [iana-time-zone](https://lib.rs/crate/iana-time-zone), which has only one single function to determine the name of the local timezone like so:

```rust
let tz_name = iana_time_zone::get_timezone()
    .expect("Could not determine timezone.");
println!("Timezone name: {tz_name}");
```

Running the code gives the following output:

> Timezone name: America/Denver

Briefly looking at the source code, it appears th crate has a wide platform support with implementations for *target_os* of aix, android, dragonfly, freebsd, haiku, hurd, illumos, ios, linux, macos, netbsd, openbsd, solaris, wasm32 and windows.

On Debian and illumos, the string appears to always represent the exact timezone set. However on FreeBSD I consistently get Europe/Berlin even if Europe/Copenhagen or Europe/Oslo has been configured. That's unexpected but not a problem, since they are all the same.

**Older answer below:** Highly unlikely to be of interest.

With the [tz-rs](https://lib.rs/crate/tz-rs) crate though, one can use the following code:

```rust
let tz = tz::TimeZone::local()
    .expect("Unable to determine timezone");
let tz_name = tz
    .find_current_local_time_type()
    .expect("Could not find local timezone type")
    .time_zone_designation();
println!("Timezone name: {tz_name}");
```

Running the above, with my timezone set to *America/Denver*, results in the following output:

> Timezone name: MST

Which is at least is an abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this might work for you:

```
let mut zone_names = HashMap::new();
zone_names.insert("-08:00", "America/Los-Angeles");
zone_names.insert("-07:00", "America/Denver");

let tz_str: &str = &chrono::Local::now().offset().to_string();
let local_tz_name = zone_names.get(&tz_str);
println!("{:?}", local_tz_name);
```

On a Unix-y system (macOS, FreeBSD), this information lives in:

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/
```

If you run `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/ ls` you'll see that Denver is included in this list, but this doesn't really get you to where you want to go either.

On my macOS machine I can run `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` and it prints out my current timezone: `Time Zone: America/Los_Angeles`.

But this might not work for you if you can't sudo on the target machine.

Actually, I just found this [crate](https://docs.rs/crate/tzdata/0.4.1). It hasn't been updated in years, but it seems to do the thing you want to do. Maybe you can gain some insight and inspiration from [it's src](https://docs.rs/crate/tzdata/0.4.1/source/src/parse.rs). Spoilers, it reads in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` and then goes from there.

Comment: This won't get the actual time zone since there are overlapping time zones.  I was hoping to get the actual time zone specified on the machine.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was a cheap shot lol. Well, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is a list of timezones. The way I've seen this type of thing implemented is more or less the way you see it above. How granular were you looking to get?

Comment: I was looking to get what the user set.  Since I have a target OS in mind, I may be able to pull it from the file system.

Comment: Yeah! I think you can pull it from the file system. I updated my answer with some of the details.